# AJAX response won't be saved into state

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

I'm trying to get some data from wikipedia and save it into `state`. 
For some reason I don't get, the `state` will be empty when the script hits `componentDidMount`

The call itself works fine..

This is my (shortened) script:

```coffeescript
define ['jquery', 'react'], ($, React) ->

  create: () ->

    React.createClass({

      getInitialState: () ->

        wikiData: {}
        userLocale: window.userLocale
        sTerm: 'dog'
        wikiDomain: '//' + window.userLocale + '.wikipedia.org'

      getWikiData: () ->

        self = @

        $.ajax

          url: self.state.wikiDomain + '/w/api.php?' +
            'action=parse' +
            '&prop=displaytitle%7Ctext' +
            '&format=json'
            '&page=' + self.state.sTerm +
            '&redirects=' +
            '&maxage=86400' +
            '&callback=?'

          async: false
          dataType: 'json'

          success: (data) ->

            if data.hasOwnProperty 'parse'
              self.setWikiData data

      setWikiData: (data) ->
        @setState wikiData: data.parse.text['*']

      componentWillMount: () ->
        @getWikiData()

      # Here is state empty again
      componentDidMount: () ->

        self = @

        $(document).ready () ->
          wikiContent = $(self.getDOMNode())
          # do things

      render: () ->
        <div className="content-inner" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: @state.wikiData}} />

})
```

Comment: Does the `self.setWiiData()` function ever get called?

Comment: I assume as the returned content from Wikipedia gets rendered.

Comment: Then I don't understand your issue.

Comment: For some reason I'm not able to get the contents of `wikiData` in `componentDidMount`. It seems that they get rendered directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple remarks we can make about your code.

### Using `async:false` in jQuery.ajax()

This option is deprecated and very dangerous. This means that you completely lock the browser until you receive a response. The effect is indeed that the state should change before `render()` is called, so I don't understand why the state would not be updated afterwards.

The best practice would be to do this request asynchronously and then when the state is eventually changed, the component will be automatically re-rendered. This way this component's load is not blocking the whole browser.

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) for more info.

### The right way of doing ajax requests on component mount.

Fortunately the react documentation contains [an article](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) that explains how do perform ajax requests on component mount. As you can see the whole work is indeed done in `componentWillMount` but they use asynchronous requests.

If you want to perform actions when the state changes, don't only use `componentDidMount` but also `componentWillUpdate` since the state you are interested in might not be available when the component did mount.

Comment: It took a while but now it clicked.. I missed the part: **When the response arrives, store the data in state, triggering a render to update your UI** My miss-assumption was, that the data would be there on the first cycle!